# Laravel 5.1.11 ACL - How to query list based on permission defined in policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a list of **posts**, which should be shown only to limited set of **users**. So I have a policy "view-posts", which returns 'true' based on some conditions. I can use **allow** or **denies** method to prohibit access to certain posts.

However how do i return list of posts (Using Eloquent) which user have access, without duplicating the conditions defined in the policy?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is for there to be a many to many relationship for the Post and User. Then, you can do something, like:

```
User::where('id', 1)->posts;
```

To get the list of posts that the user has a relationship with (or, in this case, has access to).

Each user would be associated with many posts, and each post would be associated with many users. The policy could implement this, and you would not need to duplicate the policy to generate the list.